# Why is my Digital Ocean (App Platform) server restarting when using Nextjs ISR?

Tags: next.js13, digital-ocean-apps, incremental-static-regeneration

I'm relatively new to nextjs. I have a nextjs app deployed on Digital Ocean's App platform. In my latest build I added ISR due to a dynamic route having 100k+ endpoints that update once a week at most.

Now my DO server has the following memory and restart count:

[image]

[id].js:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;

  const details = await getDetails(id);

  return {
    props: {
      details
    },
    revalidate: 3600 * 6 // 6 hours in seconds
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const validPaths = [];

  for(let i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
    const { name } = getDetails(i);
    validPaths.push({ params : {id : name.toLowerCase() }});
  }

  return {
    paths: validPaths,
    fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}
```

next.config.mjs:

```
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'X-Frame-Options',
            value: 'SAMEORIGIN',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
  generateBuildId: () => buildId,
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_BUILD_ID_ENV: buildId,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAINS: domains
  },
  swcMinify: false,
  reactStrictMode: false,
  assetPrefix: undefined,
  images: {
    domains: [domains],
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  experimental: {
    scrollRestoration: true,
    esmExternals: true
  },
  webpack: (config, {isServer}) => {
    return config;
  },
}
```

Why is my server running out of memory and how can I work around it? Why isn't my server utilizing its full 2GB before restarting?